# Confusion in 2012 paper by Austrin and Håstad regarding hardness of approximating GLST

Tags: approximation-hardness, csp

The paper in question is "[On the Usefulness of Predicates](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5662)", Per Austrin, Johan Håstad (arXiv:1204.5662 [cs.CC]).

On page 13, Example 8.2 they define a predicate $P$ which is $GLST$ with an additional accepting predicate of all $1$'s. The claim is that this predicate can be shown approximation resistant with Theorem 8.3, which requires that $P$ accept all strings $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$ such that $\prod_1 ^3 x_i = -1$ and $x_3 = -x_4$.

In particular, $P$ should accept $(1,1,-1,1)$ but the definition of $GLST$ provided requires that $x_2 \ne x_4$.

Comment: Given that their statement of Theorem 8.3 is different from Hast’s anyway, did you try to flip and/or permute some of the bits?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think by flipping $x_1$ we can resolve the issue, but if you look at Example 8.7, the authors explicitly say that $P$ accepts the troublesome inputs without mentioning any bit flipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Emil's suggestion and using trial and error, define $P'(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \equiv P(-x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$

Instances of $\text{CSP}(P')$ are isomorphic to instances of $\text{CSP}(P)$, via adding a negation in every constraint where $x_1$ appears. Then we apply the theorem on $P'$ after checking that the $\{3,4\}$ fourier coefficient is still positive. We can conclude $P'$ is resistant and therefore $P$ is as well.

Comment: Something is unsettling about resolving the question this way. Am I supposed to flip $x_1$ in my mind, when $P$ is referred to later in the paper? Like in example 8.7, should I be thinking $P'$ whenever $P$ is mentioned?

Comment: As long as it works, yes. No need to be unsettled about it; in an ideal world, the authors might have formulated the theorem and the examples consistently, or explain exactly how to apply one to the other, but life is not perfect.